# Merging Folders/Moving Files: always replace file if new one is larger

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, file-transfer

I have a few hundred folders of photos that I was able to recover. It's great since I had to really root around through other sources to build a new archive of these same photos.

However, I know that some of the images (duplicates) I currently have are of lower quality than the ones in my original archive (the ones I just recovered).

So I was thinking of merging the folders, and REPLACING the images with their counterpart ONLY if the new one has a larger file size.

End result: I'll have a single folder with all the images from my old archive, the new images I've been able to get recently, and I always have the highest-quality image for each one.

Is there any way to do this natively in Windows 7? Or install a third-party app to expand the explorer file-handling features?

Thanks!

Comment: Might not be _exactly_ what you're looking for, but check out [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/).

Comment: So the names are the same but the sizes differ? Since you mentioned recovery, if this is automated are you 100% certain that the bigger files are all uncorrupted?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but:
Total Commander has the explicit option for that in the copy dialogue.
"Copy all larger files (overwrite smaller)"